# Getting JSON Data from Redshift table

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I want  to retrieve the data in SQL from the redshift table as a json string. Are there any functions that can do this?

Postgres has row_to_json function that can be used in SQL statement to get the data as JSON.Are there nay equivalent of this in Redshift?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you can use one of those functions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

`JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT` is quite useful http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

```
select json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"star"}}','f4', 'f6');

json_extract_path_text
---------------------- 
star
```

Comment: This is  when we have the Json text. I am looking for returning json from db row data, something in lines of what is described here.  https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Comment: I suspect you'll have to craft the JSON by hand. If you are going through an application to communicate with Redshift, it should be trivial to transform the rows into a JSON object that suits your needs.

Comment: I don't think a comment prefaced with "I suspect..." conclusively answers the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out how to not have to list every item without composite types or arrays, but this should do you for generating json without needing to do string stuff.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function 
  (userid int, firstname varchar, lastname varchar, email varchar)
RETURNS varchar(max) immutable as $$
    import json
    o = {
        "userid": userid,
        "firstname": firstname,
        "lastname": lastname,
        "email": email
    }
    return json.dumps(o)
 $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```